# Nice curved brackets (in the shape of \prec and \succ)

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know how I can use the following style of angled brackets?

[image: Regular, subscripted]
[image: Big angled brackets]

Comment: For what its worth, the bottom ones are hand-drawn.

Comment: Sorry, `\LEFTRIGHT` internally uses `\left` and `\right`, so you can't use `\prec` and `\succ`. I'll find another solution.

Comment: do these have a meaning different from `\langle` and `\rangle`, or is it just a variation in appearance?  also, this scan is obviously from a published source; if you can provide a bibliographic reference, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The book is Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg.

Comment: @fctaylor25 -- thanks.  excellent reference.  they're already in unicode, U+29FC and U+29FD, so they should be in the stix/xits fonts, presumably with names `\lcurvyangle` and `\rcurvyangle`.  the angle is a bit shallower, but these are definitely intended to be the same as used in that book.  i haven't checked whether the stix fonts contain multiple sizes, but i will do so and use your reference to demonstrate that they are needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With just `pdflatex` you can use the STIX fonts and build the big version with `picture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols2}{LS1}{stixfrak}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\lcurvyangle}{\mathopen}{symbols2}{"E9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rcurvyangle}{\mathclose}{symbols2}{"EA}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\biglcurvyangle}{\mathopen{\makebiglcurvy}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigrcurvyangle}{\mathclose{\makebigrcurvy}}

\newcommand{\makebiglcurvy}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox0{$\bigg|$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{.5\ht0}%
    \addtolength{\unitlength}{.5\dp0}%
    \begin{picture}(1,2)
    \linethickness{0.6pt}\roundcap
    \put(0,0){\arc[0,90]{1}}
    \put(0,2){\arc[270,360]{1}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}

\newcommand{\makebigrcurvy}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox0{$\bigg|$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{.5\ht0}%
    \addtolength{\unitlength}{.5\dp0}%
    \begin{picture}(1,2)
    \linethickness{0.6pt}\roundcap
    \put(1,0){\arc[90,180]{1}}
    \put(1,2){\arc[180,270]{1}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}
$dF^1_{\lcurvyangle\alpha,\beta\rcurvyangle}(\xi)$

if $\lVert\lcurvyangle\zeta,\eta\rcurvyangle\rVert<1$
\[
\biglcurvyangle
  q_1,\dots,q_n,
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_1},\dots,\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_n},
  t
\bigrcurvyangle
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An implementation with only curves drawn in picture mode that also adds larger variants.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\lcurvyangle}{%
  \mathopen{%
    \nonscript\mskip2mu
    \text{\makelcurvy}%
    \nonscript\mskip2mu
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rcurvyangle}{%
  \mathclose{%
    \nonscript\mskip2mu
    \text{\makercurvy}%
    \nonscript\mskip2mu
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\biglcurvyangle}{\mathopen{\makebiglcurvy{0}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigrcurvyangle}{\mathclose{\makebigrcurvy{0}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Biglcurvyangle}{\mathopen{\makebiglcurvy{1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Bigrcurvyangle}{\mathclose{\makebigrcurvy{1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigglcurvyangle}{\mathopen{\makebiglcurvy{2}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\biggrcurvyangle}{\mathclose{\makebigrcurvy{2}}}


\newcommand{\makelcurvy}{%
  \sbox0{$\langle$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{.4\ht0}%
  \begin{picture}(2,2)
  \linethickness{0.5pt}\roundcap
  \put(0,-1){\arc[26.5,90]{2}}
  \put(0,3){\arc[270,333.5]{2}}
  \end{picture}%
}

\newcommand{\makercurvy}{%
  \sbox0{$\langle$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{.4\ht0}%
  \begin{picture}(2,2)
  \linethickness{0.5pt}\roundcap
  \put(2,-1){\arc[90,153,5]{2}}
  \put(2,3){\arc[206.5,270]{2}}
  \end{picture}%
}

\newcommand{\makebiglcurvy}[1]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox0{$\bigg|$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{.25\ht0}%
    \addtolength{\unitlength}{.25\dp0}%
    \begin{picture}(2,\numexpr4+2*#1\relax)
    \linethickness{0.6pt}\roundcap
    \put(0,\numexpr#1\relax){\arc[0,90]{2}}
    \put(0,\numexpr4+#1\relax){\arc[270,360]{2}}
    \put(2,0){\line(0,1){#1}}
    \put(2,\numexpr4+#1\relax){\line(0,1){#1}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}

\newcommand{\makebigrcurvy}[1]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox0{$\bigg|$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{.25\ht0}%
    \addtolength{\unitlength}{.25\dp0}%
    \begin{picture}(2,\numexpr4+2*#1\relax)
    \linethickness{0.6pt}\roundcap
    \put(2,\numexpr#1\relax){\arc[90,180]{2}}
    \put(2,\numexpr4+#1\relax){\arc[180,270]{2}}
    \put(0,0){\line(0,1){#1}}
    \put(0,\numexpr4+#1\relax){\line(0,1){#1}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}
$dF^1_{\lcurvyangle\alpha,\beta\rcurvyangle}(\xi)$

if $\lVert\lcurvyangle\zeta,\eta\rcurvyangle\rVert<1$
\[
\biglcurvyangle
  q_1,\dots,q_n,
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_1},\dots,\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_n},
  t
\bigrcurvyangle
\]

\[
\Biglcurvyangle
\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}
\Bigrcurvyangle
\qquad
\bigglcurvyangle
\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}
\biggrcurvyangle
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do these mean `"E9` and `"EA`? Where did you get them?

Comment: @azetina Tricks of the trade. `;-)` I looked in `stix.sty` for `\lcurvyangle`; they denote the slot in the font.

Comment: Well well. I can't imagine the cost to buy a pass to learn the trade :-) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @azetina Admission to the guild of TeX wizards just costs work on the TeXbook and exercise. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for the very nice solution. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to use it because I get the error "This NFSS system isn't set up properly." How can I fix it? Also, if you will tweak the normal-sized brackets to make them match the picture more closely, I'll change the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: @egreg -- you might be interested in the shape of a three-line version in the cited book on p.564 (576 by the acrobat counter).  ([book is on line](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf) at the harvard math department.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The vertical alignment in those formulas is abominable. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg -- true, but if you were working with metal type (monotype -- pretty sure it's modern 8a, done by addison-wesley's crackerjack monotype operator), how would you have done it while retaining your sanity?

Comment: @fctaylor25 I added an even larger version as suggested by barbara beeton; also I fixed some mistakes in the `picture` only version.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The mistake is, of course, insisting in two story fraction in the radical at the denominator that unbalances the big fraction.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, the code is far away from beautiful but it shows which unicodes you may use for this and how do define your brackets with those. In the end, you see 4 different fonts, which you may choose. You can find more of them [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/29fd/fontsupport.htm).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\myL}{\symbol{"29FC}}
\newcommand*{\myR}{\symbol{"29FD}}
\newcommand*{\mySmallL}{\symbol{"227A}}
\newcommand*{\mySmallR}{\symbol{"227B}}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\myBrak{\text{{\fontspec{stix-regular.otf}\symbol{"227A}}}}{{\text{\fontspec{stix-regular.otf}\symbol{"227B}}}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\myBigBrak{\text{{\fontspec{stix-regular.otf}\symbol{"29FC}}}}{{\text{\fontspec{stix-regular.otf}\symbol{"29FD}}}}   
% note: you wont be able to use the starred version of these commands. 

\begin{document}
        $-dF^1_{\myBrak{\alpha,\beta}}(\zeta)$,

        $\in\qquad\text{if}\quad\left\|\myBrak{\zeta,\eta}\right\|$

        $=\myBigBrak{q_1, \dots, q_n, \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_n}, t}$

    \bigskip
    {\fontspec{quivira.otf}\myL{\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\myL{\fontspec{stix-regular.otf}\myL{\fontspec{Cambria Math}\myL\myR}\myR}\myR}\myR}

    {\fontspec{quivira.otf}\mySmallL{\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\mySmallL{\fontspec{stix-regular.otf}\mySmallL{\fontspec{Cambria Math}\mySmallL\mySmallR}\mySmallR}\mySmallR}\mySmallR} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Those look great. I noticed that the large brackets (in the original) look like they're made from two quarter circles. Do you think you could make some like that?

Comment: You could do such thing with TikZ but I am not the right person to ask. But if you draw your own symbol, it will not fit visually to the smaller version. I understood, that their meaning is the same here. If it isn't, you should delete that part from your question, as it is distracting from your desired result.

Comment: Also, I just have regular LaTeX.

Comment: @fctaylor25 I just needed Lua (or Xe) in order to load various fonts. When you find your symbol in one of the PDFLaTeX packages or draw it by your self with TikZ or alike, you can still use my code in order to use it.